# VBA If range [J:K] not empty, then copy [H:I] to the end of [J:K], else offset

Tags: excel, vba

I have two ranges, [H23:I32] and [J23:K50].
I need to copy values from [H23:I32] to [J23:K50] if [J23:K50] is empty, and if [J23:K50] is not empty I need to find the last row and add [H23:I32] below.

The "copy if empty" works, but the "add to the end of the list" doesn't unfortunately.
It does something, but clearly not the thing I need.

```
 Sub Total_Loop()
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim c  As Range
    
        For Each c In Range("J23:K50" & Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row)
           If c.Value <> "" Then
           Range("J23:K50" & Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row + 1) = Range("H23:I32")
           Else: c.Value = c.Offset(, -2).Value
        
        End If
        Next
        
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    End Sub
```

Any suggestions how to fix this?

EDIT: After a lot of struggle I found a suitable solution!

```
Sub MoveData()
Dim lrow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Loot")


If WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Range("J23:K50")) = 0 Then
     ws.Range("H23:I32").Copy
     ws.Range("J23").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Else
     lrow = ws.Range("J23:K50").Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
     ws.Range("H23:I32").Copy
     ws.Range("J" & lrow + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Start by removing the `50` from `Range("J23:K50"`.

Comment: Thanks! For some reason instead of copying [H:I] to the end of [J:K] my macro starts wiping data J23 > K23 > J24 > K24 one cell at a time

Comment: When we search from the bottom and hit a non-empty cell, e.g. `J50` or `J100`, is the cell below this cell where you want to copy the data? Unless the cell is above `J23`, e.g. `J15`,  when you would want to copy starting with `J23`? Please do confirm if this is true

Comment: First of, I don't want to go below J50. I am trying to do everything within J23:K50. I am not supposed to check above J23:K23 and below J50:K50.

Comment: I am trying a different approach now with:

Comment: Sub MoveData()
Dim lrow As Long

If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("J23:K50")) = 0 Then
     Range("H23:I32").Copy Range("J23")
Else
   lrow = Range("J23:K50").Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).row
   Range("H23:I32").Copy Range("J" & lrow + 1)
End If
End Sub

Comment: But this gets me stuck with copying formulas instead of copying values. Also I cannot do paragraphs in my comments, thus the comment spam